# htaccess changing automaticly the RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to fix this error I had after adding these rules for HTTPS and non-www to `.htaccess` file on top

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
```

it did fix the HTTPS and non-www but it messed this rule

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ product.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

it's now changing this URL whenever there is no HTTPS or no www

- from : `www.example.com/product/2443`
- to   : `www.example.com/product.php/2443?p=2443`

I want it to go back to this again:

- `www.example.com/product/2443`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've put the directives in the wrong order. Your canonical redirects (HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www) need to be at the top of the `.htaccess` file before your internal rewrites.

Also, since you are internally rewriting to a file with the same basename as the requested URL-path you will need to make sure that MultiViews is disabled to prevent mod_negotiation from internally issuing a subrequest for `/product.php/2443` before mod_rewrite is able to process the request. For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file add the following to ensure that MultiViews is disabled:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

You will need to clear your browser cache, since these erroneous (301 - permanent) redirects will have been cached by the browser.

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
> ```

Reverse these two rules to avoid a double redirect when requesting HTTP + non-www. However, you should leave these as they are if you are planning to implement HSTS.

The `QSA` flag is not required on either of these rules.

And the capturing `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. `(.*)`) is superfluous. It would be more efficient to just use `^` (or `$`) - an assertion - since it only needs to be successful for everything, it doesn't need to actually match anything.

Comment: it didn't work, i cleared my browser and the code is already at the top.
i don't know why it's changing the url, thanks anyway.

Comment: @DevWayAgence Also make sure that MultiViews is disabled. I've updated my answer. If this still fails after clearing your browser (and any other intermediary) caches then please update your question with your complete `.htaccess` file. Also, checking the HTTP response(s) in the browser (network traffic) may be necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.
after i add  `Options -MultiViews` the URL stopped redirecting